# Time convertion to Year, Month, Day, Hour, Second(In words)

Tags: python, datetime

I wanna convert this **2022-05-17T06:44:32+00:00** to **2022-May-17 06:44:32**
What are the ways to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Look into the Python date libraries. Or any tutorial or text book on Python.

Comment: Looks like you just need to replace `05` with `May`, remove the `T`, and strip off everything after the seconds.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: for example [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat), then [datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

I would first clean your input by removing that letter in the middle which you don't seem to need and I'm not quite sure what it is and everything after the "+" since you don't need it and then convert the month, the code would look something like this.

```
date_parsed = re.sub("[a-zA-Z]", " ", "2022-05-17T06:44:32+00:00").split("+")[0]
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_parsed, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date.strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H-%M-%S")
```

I would suggest you look into the docs for [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) here is a site with a [cheat sheet](https://pythonexamples.org/python-datetime-format/) so you can get your desired output.

thanks to @Learning and @BoarGules comments I think the better solution is

```
t = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-05-17T06:44:32+00:00")
t.strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H-%M-%S")
```

Comment: If we knew the format of your input this could have been done without parsing the input.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! I have learned a lot from this alone! I will remember the necessary steps to get the job done.

Comment: I think its in ISO because I tried this, t = datetime.fromisoformat("2022-05-17T06:44:32+00:00")  but it didnt change the numbers into words.

Comment: @Learning It is ISO format. Once you convert it to datetime (which you've already done) you can do a `t.strftime()` call. To get `May` instead of  `05` use directive `%B` in the format string.